# Spring MVC and CDI (Weld)

Tags: spring-mvc, cdi, weld, jsr330, jsr299

Is it possible to use Spring MVC and Weld in a Web Application? I'm also using WildFly 10.1 as my Server and RestEasy.

Comment: Regarding this article, it is possible : http://www.andygibson.net/blog/article/implementing-spring-mvc-with-cdi-and-java-ee-6/

Comment: This article seems to predate the integration provided by RestEasy.